# Browser not rendering the updated value but Vue DevTools does

Tags: vue.js

I am using the drop-down inside a table column to change logger level, code is as below:
Loggers is an array of loggers and I am tracking and displaying the value through selectedLevel attribute(see the attached screenshot). What I have noticed is if page gets refreshed it displays the updated data but not without refreshing.

```
<tr v-for="(logger, index) in loggers" :key="index">
                  <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
                  <td>{{ logger.logger }}</td>
                  <td>{{ logger.level }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <b-dropdown
                      boundary="viewport"
                      id="dropdown-dropup"
                      size="sm"
                      :text="logger.selectedLevel"
                      class="m-2"
                    >
                      <b-dropdown-item
                        v-for="level in logger.allLevel"
                        :key="level"
                        @click.prevent="changeLevel(level, index)"
                        >{{ level }}</b-dropdown-item
                      >
                    </b-dropdown>
                  </td>
```

my changeLevel method is like this:

```
 changeLevel(level, index) {
      // alert(index + " " + level);
      this.loggers[index].selectedLevel = level;
      this.levelChanged = true;
    },
```

and allLevel is a variable `var allLevel = ["WARN", "DEBUG", "INFO", "ERROR", "FATAL"];`

[image]

This is how I am populating the loggers object

```
getLevel() {
  if (
    this.loggers.find(item => {
      if (item.logger == this.searchData) {
        return true;
      } else return;
      false;
    })
  ) {
    this.popUpListener("This class is already listed!");
  } else {
    var logger;
    var allLevel = ["WARN", "DEBUG", "INFO", "ERROR", "FATAL"];
    var loggerFound;
    if (
      this.filteredLoggersList.find(item => {
        if (item.logger == this.searchData) {
          logger = item;
          return true;
        } else false;
      })
    ) {
      logger.allLevel = allLevel;
      logger.selectedLevel = "Select & update";
      this.loggers.push(logger);
      alert(logger);
    }
```

I am using autocomplete feature, so I am using here filteredLoggersList which is a list of all the loggers based on user search in the search box and when matched and selected I am simply adding into loggers array.

video here: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfcYKVEFqpw)

[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfcYKVEFqpw):

Comment: Make sure that all objects in this.loggers are reactive.

Comment: how are you creating `loggers` object.

Comment: @Anatoly How do I make all objects in this.loggers reactive?

Comment: they become reactive automatically if you oass them as prop or if you store them in a 'data' section of a component

Comment: Is loggers part of your component `data`?

Comment: @Anatoly, I can see the value being updated in Vue dev tools, means they are reactive right? it's just not being updated on UI.

Comment: @sthotakura yes loggers array is a part of the data component.

Comment: @Anatoly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYm5vlQuoWc

Comment: @sthotakura https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYm5vlQuoWc

Comment: you should not directly push the loggers array, you should create a new reference of that array for each set. if you directly push the array the data will be set, but wont render

Comment: @AliKleit would you help me with a code snippet on how to fix it?

Comment: sure, I hope my answer was helpful.if not, I think it would be better to post a snippet of your code and explain more your logic

Comment: I have tried to repro your issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-varahamihira-elcm1) - I couldn't repro. it seems to update fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a new reference of the `loggers` array. try the following:

```js
changeLevel(level, index) {

    let loggers = [...this.loggers]

    loggers[index].selectedLevel = level

    this.loggers = loggers;
    this.levelChanged = true;
},
getLevel() {

    const itemFound = this.loggers.find(item => item.logger === this.searchData)

    if (itemFound) {
        this.popUpListener("This class is already listed!");
    } else {

        var allLevel = ["WARN", "DEBUG", "INFO", "ERROR", "FATAL"];

        let logger = this.filteredLoggersList.find(item => item.logger === this.searchData)

        // debug the logger value
        console.log({logger})

        if (logger) {

            logger.allLevel = allLevel;
            logger.selectedLevel = "Select & update";

            // creating a new reference for the array logger
            this.loggers = [...this.loggers, logger];

            //alert(logger);
        }
    }
}
```

Your objects should be `immutable`. thus having a new reference each time you alter your objects. vue's render uses a `Virtual DOM` to compare objects with `DOM` so if you modify your object `loggers` directly `VDOM` will not know what is actually rendered inside that object, so it won't render.

I advise you to check how `VDOM` renders objects and how `immutability` works and check out some of the best practices, [good examples here](https://dev.to/antonio_pangall/best-practices-to-keep-objects-and-arrays-immutable-in-javascript-3nmm).

Comment: the issue remains same. the problem is not with data being updated..it's with the rendering issue. If you see my video (link given in original question) you would notice the value is getting updated , but not getting rendered.

Comment: so the poblem is in the `changeLevel`?

Comment: No, it's changing the level. Problem is here  :text="logger.selectedLevel"

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you try updating your `changeLevel` function to that?

Comment: It's working thank you. Would you explain why have you suggested to create a new reference for the loggers?

Comment: @skr glad that helped! I edited my answer and added an explanation at the bottom